# I will not in any case kick the ball or I will in any case not kick the ball?

Tags: grammar

> I will not in any case kick the ball.
>
> I will in any case not kick the ball.
>
> I in any case will not kick the ball.
>
> I will not kick in any case the ball.

I think only the fourth one is wrong, and all of the others seem fine to me. Please tell me if there are any wrong ones (and why), because after looking at them for so long, I just lost my sense of English. Also, please tell me if some of them have to be used with commas like below:

I, in any case, will not kick the ball.

Comment: "In no case will I kick the ball" and "I will not kick the ball in any case" are both much clearer than *any* of your examples.

Comment: I am sure that is. I just want to know if these are possible to use and if they have to be used with commas.

Comment: The 3rd and 4th would be OK with commas.  Note that the first two do not mean the same thing.

Comment: Only with commas?

Comment: You can always argue over commas.

Comment: I wonder if you could find an example that wouldn't seem unreal -- sorry, but I have a hard time believing that someone would use this sentence about kicking a ball.

Comment: "I ain't gonna kick that ball, no way, no how."

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need commas if you want people to understand the sentence and keep the flow going.  Grammatically it's optional.

Answer (score 0):

> I will not kick in any case the ball.

This is wrong because you are splitting the object and the verb with a prepositional phrase that belongs to the clause "kick the ball". If instead you say

> I will not kick the ball in any case.

that's perfectly fine and of all the options, sounds the clearest to me.

I agree that all the others are fine, but I also think all of them could be improved by enclosing the prepositional phrase in commas. I don't know how correct that would be, though.

---

Please anyone correct me on my use of grammatical terminology.

Answer (score 0):

The first two are both grammatical but have slightly different meanings.

In

> I will not in any case kick the ball.

the "in any case" functions as an intensifier for the "not": it means something like "There are no circumstances under which I will kick the ball".

In

> I will in any case not kick the ball.

the "in any case" could mean literally "whatever the circumstances", but usually means "despite X" or "even allowing for X" or "whichever way X turns out" (where X is something that has already been referred to)". For example

> I don't know whether I can come to the match or not. I will in any case not kick the ball.

Comment: Do I have to put "in any case" in commas or is it just optional?